# Java AWT: How to know which mouse button was released after a mouseDragged event?

Tags: java, events, awt, mouse

If I have two mouse buttons held down, then drag the mouse, then release either button, how can I determine which button was released? The buttons held down are retrievable with a MouseEvent.getModifiersEx(), but there doesn't seem to be any way to tell which one was released, since all buttons pressed before the release event triggers are stored in that mask:

```
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    int b1 = MouseEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK;
    int b2 = MouseEvent.BUTTON2_DOWN_MASK;

    System.out.println(e.getButton()) // prints "0" when the mousereleased
                                      // event follows a mouseDragged
                                      // event

    if ((mouseEvent.getModifiersEx() & b1) == b1) {
      System.out.println("button 1 released");
    } else if ((mouseEvent.getModifiersEx() & b2) == b2) {
      System.out.println("button 2 released");
    }

    /* 
       Following a mouseDragged event, assuming button 1 and button 2 
       were pressed before either was released, the first if clause 
       evaluates to true regardless of which button was actually released.
       In other words, releasing button 2 in this scenario will print
       "button 1 released"
     */

}
```

It's easy if the mouseReleased event is preceded by a mousePressed event, but when it is preceded by mouseDragged, I can't simply call getButton()...

Comment: Please post your best [mcve] attempt to show us how your code is ***not*** working right.

Comment: Have you tried `SwingUtilities#isLeftMouseButton` and `isRightMouseButton`?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks for the feedback. I replaced the abstract code block with a concrete one to better illustrate my question.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I don't know why I thought getButton was returning 0 following a drag event earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but when it is preceded by mouseDragged, I can't simply call getButton()...

Why not?

If you want the state of the mouse release after dragging has stopped, perhaps use a boolean flag in your MouseAdapter and set it to true when dragging. Something like:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

public class MouseButtons extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 800;
    private static final int PREF_H = 650;

    public MouseButtons() {
        MyMouseAdapter myMouse = new MyMouseAdapter();
        addMouseListener(myMouse);
        addMouseMotionListener(myMouse);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    private class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
        private boolean dragging = false;

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            String text = "";
            int button = e.getButton();
            if (button == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
                text = "Button 1";
            } else if (button == MouseEvent.BUTTON2) {
                text = "Button 2";
            } else if (button == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
                text = "Button 3";
            }

            if (dragging) {
                System.out.println(text + " just finished dragging");
            } else {
                System.out.println(text + " not recently dragging");
            }
            dragging = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            dragging = true;
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MouseButtons");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new MouseButtons());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Unless I'm completely misunderstanding your question, and if so then I ask you to clarify it a bit.